# Maximum value in a 3D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Let say if have a 3D matrix `A=randi([1, 9],[2 2 9])`, how do I find the maximum value from all the slices and return only one maximum value? Thanks!

Comment: the total maximum value? `max(A(:))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use MATLAB's [max](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function as follows:

```
max(A(:))
```

Example:

```
A=randi([1, 9],[2 2 2])

A(:,:,1) =

 5     1
 9     4

A(:,:,2) =

 1     8
 8     8

max(A(:))

ans =
 9
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks!